I want to show Exit dialog box in my app before user leave the app in Roku
I want to show Exit dialog box in my app before user leave the app. To resolve the issue, I have follow below link which has all the necessary steps to show dialog box. But in my case same code is not working.
Link : https://medium.com/@amitdogra70512/confirmation-dialog-on-app-exit-in-roku-b305d91acec8
In my case, dialog box is not getting display and app close directly without waiting for dialog box.
Any suggestions and help are welcome.
Thank you

I read the article you referenced and duplicated the code. It works. I recommend deleting this question and creating a new one with your code.

I see this link guide to show exit dialog correct, maybe your code is wrong
you need to put dialog in MainScene.brs and check key back press.
please check:

MainScene: onKeyEvent with key back => you need return true revent app exit


This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
